# Who populates the Millennium as mortals?

Tags: eschatology, premillennialism, immortality

I am having difficulty reconciling several End Times passages together, so let's see if anyone can help me. There's a lot to quote from, so I'm removing the white space.

I hold to pre-Millennial beliefs. My trouble lies in determining who the mortals will be during the Millennium, as you can see in the following passages:

> I tell you this, brothers: flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God, nor does the perishable inherit the imperishable. Behold! I tell you a mystery. We shall not all sleep, but we shall all be changed, in a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, **at the last trumpet**. For **the trumpet will sound, and the dead will be raised imperishable, and we shall be changed. For this perishable body must put on the imperishable, and this mortal body must put on immortality.** When the perishable puts on the imperishable, and the mortal puts on immortality, then shall come to pass the saying that is written: **'Death is swallowed up in victory.'** 'O death, where is your victory? O death, where is your sting?'
> (1 Corinthians 15:50-55)

> And another angel, a third, followed them, saying with a loud voice, '**If anyone worships the beast and its image and receives a mark on his forehead or on his hand, he also will drink the wine of God's wrath, poured full strength into the cup of his anger**, and he will be tormented with fire and sulfur in the presence of the holy angels and in the presence of the Lamb. **And the smoke of their torment goes up forever and ever, and they have no rest, day or night, these worshipers of the beast and its image, and whoever receives the mark of its name.**'
> (Revelation 14:9-11)

> **And I saw the beast and the kings of the earth with their armies gathered to make war against him who was sitting on the horse and against his army.** And the beast was captured, and with it the false prophet who in its presence had done the signs by which he deceived those who had received the mark of the beast and those who worshiped its image. These two were thrown alive into the lake of fire that burns with sulfur. **And the rest were slain by the sword that came from the mouth of him who was sitting on the horse**, and all the birds were gorged with their flesh.
> (Revelation 19:19-21)

> Then I saw thrones, and seated on them were those to whom the authority to judge was committed. Also I saw the souls of those who had been beheaded for the testimony of Jesus and for the word of God, **and who had not worshiped the beast or its image and had not received its mark on their foreheads or their hands. They came to life and reigned with Christ for a thousand years. The rest of the dead did not come to life until the thousand years were ended.** This is the first resurrection. Blessed and holy is the one who shares in the first resurrection! Over such the second death has no power, but they will be priests of God and of Christ, and they will reign with him for a thousand years.
> (Revelation 20:4-6)

> '**For behold, I create new heavens and a new earth, and the former things shall not be remembered or come into mind.** But be glad and rejoice forever in that which I create; for behold, I create Jerusalem to be a joy, and her people to be a gladness. I will rejoice in Jerusalem and be glad in my people; no more shall be heard in it the sound of weeping and the cry of distress. **No more shall there be in it an infant who lives but a few days, or an old man who does not fill out his days, for the young man shall die a hundred years old, and the sinner a hundred years old shall be accursed.** They shall build houses and inhabit them; they shall plant vineyards and eat their fruit. They shall not build and another inhabit; they shall not plant and another eat; for **like the days of a tree shall the days of my people be**, and my chosen shall long enjoy the work of their hands. They shall not labor in vain or bear children for calamity, for they shall be the offspring of the blessed of the LORD, and their descendants with them. Before they call I will answer; while they are yet speaking I will hear. The wolf and the lamb shall graze together; the lion shall eat straw like the ox, and dust shall be the serpent's food. They shall not hurt or destroy in all my holy mountain,' says the LORD.
> (Isaiah 65:17-25)

That verse, Isaiah 65:20, is the one that brings me the most difficulty. If the saints and everyone who doesn't worship the Antichrist rule and reign with Christ for 1,000 years, and after those 1,000 years death is defeated forever (Revelation 20:14; 21:4; Isaiah 25:7-8), then ***who are these people that are dying 100 years young or older in the future, presumably during the Millennium, as mortals***? It seems like a black and white situation during the Great Tribulation: you either believe and resist the beast or you don't. Can someone explain how all this works to me? Thanks.

Some passages that may be relevant:

> Then everyone who survives of all the nations that have come against Jerusalem shall go up year after year to worship the King, the LORD of hosts, and to keep the Feast of Booths.
> (Zechariah 14:16)
>
> Therefore a curse devours the earth, and its inhabitants suffer for their guilt; therefore the inhabitants of the earth are scorched, and few men are left.
> (Isaiah 24:6)
>
> For thus it shall be in the midst of the earth among the nations, as when an olive tree is beaten, as at the gleaning when the grape harvest is done.
> (Isaiah 24:13)
>
> On this mountain the LORD of hosts will make for all peoples a feast of rich food, a feast of well-aged wine, of rich food full of marrow, of aged wine well refined. And he will swallow up on this mountain the covering that is cast over all peoples, the veil that is spread over all nations. **He will swallow up death forever;** and the Lord GOD will wipe away tears from all faces, and the reproach of his people he will take away from all the earth, for the LORD has spoken.
> (Isaiah 25:6-8)
>
> Thus says the LORD: I have returned to Zion and will dwell in the midst of Jerusalem, and Jerusalem shall be called the faithful city, and the mountain of the LORD of hosts, the holy mountain. Thus says the LORD of hosts: **Old men and old women shall again sit in the streets of Jerusalem, each with staff in hand because of great age**.
> (Zechariah 8:3-4)
>
> Then Death and Hades were thrown into the lake of fire. This is the second death, the lake of fire. And if anyone's name was not found written in the book of life, he was thrown into the lake of fire.
> (Revelation 20:14-15)

I also have an interesting theory, based on the wording of several verses in 2 Peter 3, that the last trumpet isn't blown until many years after the Tribulation, and in several cases where it says "in/on that day" it's referring to the "day of the LORD" as the 1,000 year Millennium. Just a theory.

Comment: It is not helpful to continue throwing pejorative language around (fascist, Nazi).  If you don't like the rules of this site, you can take it up on the [Meta site](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/).  But I'd encourage you to learn why these rules are in place.  The meta posts I've already shared are relevant, and so is this one: [I'm new here and I'm having some difficulty understanding guidelines for questions](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/6007/21576).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43203/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-who-populates-the-millennium-as-mortals).

Comment: Just so you are aware the historic majority view appears to have been to deny a literal millenium at all (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amillennialism). You probably know this, but I was personally unaware of this for most of my life being raised in an environment that assumed that there was only pre or post millenialism and no other options.

Comment: It says " They came to life and reigned with Christ for a thousand years. The rest of the dead did not come to life until the thousand years were ended." Compare this against 1 cor 15 : "the last trumpet. For the trumpet will sound, and the dead will be raised". compare w/ john 5:26&29. again the resurection of the dead... Who is it that is Raised to life BEFORE the judgement... Compare to Eph 2: 1 "And he made you alive who were dead in tresppasses and sins " ...

Comment: @L1R Great logic! "The dead were resurrected" "These people were resurrected" Therefore, these passages **must** be speaking of the same people being resurrected at the same time! Yeah you'll get really far in Biblical theology with that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always understood the original question to be answered by the possibility that children will be born during the Millenium, and thus required to decide their allegiance.  They will either align themselves with Christ and His kingdom during the Millenium, or reject His authority.  Those who reject His authority may die "young" during the Millenium. Those who are around at the end, when Satan is released to deceive the nations, will be led in rebellion against Christ.  Otherwise, how could there be people around to be deceived at that time?

Revelation 20:7-10:

> And when the thousand years are ended, Satan will be released from his prison and will come out to deceive the nations that are at the four corners of the earth, Gog and Magog, to gather them for battle; their number is like the sand of the sea. And they marched up over the broad plain of the earth and surrounded the camp of the saints and the beloved city, but fire came down from heaven and consumed them, and the devil who had deceived them was thrown into the lake of fire and sulfur where the beast and the false prophet were, and they will be tormented day and night forever and ever.

Answer (score 3):

Pre-tribulation premillennialists argue that the mortals who populate the millennial kingdom will be those who become Christians during the tribulation, following the rapture:

> Pretribulationists [...] posit that a vast number of Jewish people and Gentiles will be saved during the tribulation.  Many of these will be alive in their natural bodies when Christ returns to earth, and they will be spared the judgment the rest of the Christ-rejecting world experiences at that time.  They will enter and populate the millennial kingdom in their natural bodies, and unfortunately they will even produce some rebellious offspring. (*Moody Bible Commentary*)

Post-tribulation premillennialists, on the other hand, argue that the mortals populating the millennial kingdom will be those who were unbelievers at the time of Christ's return:

> When Christ comes at the end of the tribulation he will *defeat* all the forces arrayed against him, but that does not mean he will kill or annihilate all of them.  Many will simply surrender without trusting Christ, and will thus enter the millennium as unbelievers.  And during the entire period of the millennium no doubt many will be converted to Christ and become believers as well. (Wayne Grudem, *Systematic Theology*, 1133)

Answer (score 2):

Revelation 7:14 refers to those who will be alive on earth during the Millenium as follows:

> "These are they which came out of great tribulation, and have washed their robes, and made them white in the blood of the Lamb."

Clearly they are not unbelievers, but they are righteous ones who survive the tribulation and enjoy the blessings of God's Kingdom because of their faith in the Christ.

Answer (score 2):

This question have I pondered endlessly! ***THE ROD OF IRON*** of His rule is the key. This phrase is quoted in Psalm 2:9, Rev.2:27, Rev.12:5 and Rev.19:5. The Rev deals almost in its entirety with the Tribulation and 1,000 year reign. The verses are too long to print here so please review them, preferably in a King James Bible :)

King David was a Prophet/King, so it is doubtlessly true that he is speaking of the 1,000 years in Psalm 2:9.

Clearly mortals will enter the Reign, saved and unsaved. These are people who survived the Tribulation. This is why Satan is loosed a little season, Rev.20:3, at the end; he will gather Israel's enemies for one last, doomed attack. Ergo,the need for the ROD OF IRON rule of the 1,000 years is obviously necessary, because renegades will exist that need to be controlled. Those in resurrection bodies will assist the Christ in enforcing the law.
I have cogitated on the very real possibility that there is yet another resurrection, not mentioned in Scripture, that takes place for the saved just prior to the New Heavens and the New Earth being formed. There shall be no reprobates in the new creation.

Some confusion can enter the picture when we do not realize that the Reign, to be held on THIS EARTH, is NOT the dissolution event of this present Earth and cosmos.  2Peter 3(verses 10 and 12) describe this dissolving of the present material cosmos that will take place **AFTER** the 1,000 year Reign. A totally new world and cosmos will then exist, and the New Jerusalem will be suspended above the new Earth; Rev.3:12 and Rev.21:2. There shall exist NO renegades THERE, as they were done in during Satan's last stand!

Since the Rev makes no mention whatsoever of Gentiles being saved during the Tribulation, I posit that only unsaved and saved Hebrews will enter the Reign. Makes perfect sense because the Trib is designed to get Israel in line with their Messiah as per 'Jacob's Trouble', Jeremiah 30:7.
This verse clearly says the Hebrews will be 'saved out of' that last seven years of world history as we know it.   The "Times of the Gentiles" Luke 21:24, are over and done with when they are taken up in Harpazo, the Greek word that 'rapture' comes from. This same verse also speaks of the Diaspora. Powerful verse!

I still haven't answered the original question; forgive me, apologists tend to be long-winded, as we have to prove our case :)

### Yes, mortals will enter the Reign

They will be ruled by Messiah and His regents, those of us in glorified bodies. Earthly kings use this exact method.   The best Bible teacher I ever listened to once commented that the 1,000 year Reign will be a 'police state'...his exact words. The rod of iron will be exercised.
The transition into the new creation of another Heaven, Earth and Jerusalem, necessitates, at least in my deductions, ANOTHER resurrection of saved mortals from the Reign. We have been told that we see through a glass darkly, 1Cor 13:12, and that when we see Him, we will know a great deal more than has been revealed to us at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Pardon me if I'm jumping the gun, but there seems to be two requirements for either the Winepress or the Resurrection.

1. Winepress - Those who worshiped the beast or the anti-christ, and
   those who accepted the mark.
2. Resurrection - Those who did not worship the beast, those who did
   not accept the mark, rather those who were faithful to Jesus Christ
   and held the testimony of God and Jesus Christ to their end.

It seems to me that simple un-believers aren't actually wine-pressed or killed. I could be wrong. But there will be a group of people, however small, of those who do not believe in Christ but did not accept the mark of the beast nor worship the beast or his image or the false prophet, nor the anti-christ.

It's possible that these people were just people who never had the faith, but didn't give in to the system.

There are a lot of anarchists out there who, even if they weren't a Christian,  would see this marking, and worshiping the Beast as a sort of 1984 Big Brother type situation and reject it entirely, without having faith in Christ.

It seems most likely the inhabitants of this section

1. Don't believe in Jesus Christ, but never bowed a knee to the devil
   and his 'boys'
2. Would be Jews.

The people of Jerusalem will be under siege by these very same people, so why would they accept the system? They probably wouldn't, but that doesn't mean they'd run to Christ either.

To me, from reading the verses you've supplied, and knowing from Zechariah 14:16 that there will be people after the Winepress who are mortals to be ruled over by the Immortal Christians and Christ himself, it seems like the only possible candidates who could fit the bill would be the unsaved and in-condemned people.

If they were not saved, they are not worthy of the Resurrection. 
If they were not condemned (did not take the mark/ worship the beast or his image) I'm not seeing that they're included in that Winepress.

Comment: Jacob, welcome to Christianity.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how an SE Q&A site work.  This isn't a discussion forum, which means that unless your answer (post) [directly answers the question, and is supported](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), it won't remain.

Comment: I have edited this answer to make it more coherent and presentable, but that didn't resolve all of the requirements for a good answer. Please edit your answer again after reading up on [how to write a good answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) at the link provided.

Answer (score 1):

According to one historicist (Ellis Skolfield), the millenium and the tribulation are concurrent. Skolfield argues that the word for millennium used in the Greek, chillioi, is an indefinite plural, hence can refer to multiple thousands of years. Thus we are in the millenium since Christ has ascended and is our king. We are also in the tribulation, which began as soon as Christ rose.

Thus to answer your question, YOU are one of the people who populates the millennial kingdom as a mortal.

Comment: It's plural because 1,000 is plural... What you're arguing is like saying that because 5 is plural, "five" could be referring to 500.

Comment: "Thus we are in the millen[n]ium" - what? *That's* your reasoning? Because you've interpreted "1,000" as "multiple thousands of years", we're in the Millennium now? Really? Christ has ascended, but where does it say He is our King? In Acts 7:55, Jesus was standing beside the Father. In Revelation 20:2, Satan is to be bound during the Millennium. Look around: does it look like Satan is bound, not to deceive the nations any longer (3), until the Millennium is over?

Comment: In Matthew 24:21, Jesus describes the tribulation as "a great tribulation, such as has not occurred since the beginning of the world until now, nor ever will". The Antichrist himself is described as being present during this tribulation. If you bother to read Daniel 6-12 and the middle part of Revelation you will see clearly that the tribulation is described multiple times in multiple different ways as being 7 years long exactly (in 360 day years), and the great tribulation is the latter 3.5 years, after the Abomination of Desolation (Daniel 11; Revelation 13; Daniel 7).

Answer (score 0):

Zechariah 14:16 "Then all the survivors from the nations that came against Jerusalem will go up year after year to worship the King, the LORD of Hosts, and to celebrate the Feast of Tabernacles."

A kingdom must have a king, rulers or governors, and subjects, otherwise, it is not a kingdom. Obviously, the subjects will not have the same Divine revelations as the rulers. The rulers will operate in the same capacity as in the nature, character and function of the Lord Jesus-Christ and bring the subjects up to scratch in the knowledge of the Lord.

The rulers of the kingdom will have an incorruptible flesh and bone body just like Jesus at his resurrection. They will have two garments or interchangeable bodies as described in Ezekiel 44: one fine white linen garment (glorified body) to minister to God, one woollen garment to minister to or to teach people.

*"Survivors from the nations"* speaks of unbelievers who will be alive in the Millennium. The rulers of the Kingdom will be kinsmen redeemers to the unsaved world. This means that they will sit under us to learn the ways of the Lord until they mature in the knowledge of the Lord.

In the Kingdom, there will also be new believers and believers who never matured in their spiritual walk who will learn from the High Priests (rulers).

*"Came against Jerusalem"*, the Hebrew word for Jerusalem is Yerushalayim (plural): the heavenly Jerusalem and the earthly Jerusalem. Jerusalem also means the teachers of the rain of Divine revelatory understanding. The Bible says that Jesus will come like the rain.

Deuteronomy 32:2 "Let my teaching (doctrines and revelations) fall like rain and my speech settle like dew, like gentle rain on new grass, like showers on tender plants."

Hosea 6:3 "Then shall we know, if we follow on to know the LORD: his going forth is prepared as the morning; and he shall come unto us as the rain, as the latter and former rain unto the earth."

**Every priest had to be a Levite. The verses below make a clear shift among the priesthood.
Ezekiel 44:6-14 - These priests will serve in the Outer Court**

“Now say to the rebellious, to the house of Israel, ‘Thus says the Lord God: “O house of Israel, let Us have no more of all your abominations. When you brought in foreigners, uncircumcised in heart and uncircumcised in flesh, to be in My sanctuary to defile it—My house—and when you offered My food, the fat and the blood, then they broke My covenant because of all your abominations. And you have not kept charge of My holy things, but you have set others to keep charge of My sanctuary for you.” Thus says the Lord God: “No foreigner, uncircumcised in heart or uncircumcised in flesh, shall enter My sanctuary, including any foreigner who is among the children of Israel.
“And the Levites who went far from Me, when Israel went astray, who strayed away from Me after their idols, they shall bear their iniquity. Yet they shall be ministers in My sanctuary, as gatekeepers of the house and ministers of the house; they shall slay the burnt offering and the sacrifice for the people, and they shall stand before them to minister to them. Because they ministered to them before their idols and caused the house of Israel to fall into iniquity, therefore I have raised My hand in an oath against them,” says the Lord God, “that they shall bear their iniquity. And they shall not come near Me to minister to Me as priests, nor come near any of My holy things, nor into the Most Holy Place; but they shall bear their shame and their abominations which they have committed. Nevertheless, I will make them keep charge of the temple, for all its work, and for all that has to be done in it.

**THE LEVITES WHO WERE THE SONS OF ZADOK
These priests will serve in the Holy Place and the Holy of Holies or the Mishkhan**

Ezekiel 44:15-31 “But the priests, the Levites, the sons of Zadok, who kept charge of My sanctuary when the children of Israel went astray from Me, they shall come near Me to minister to Me; and they shall stand before Me to offer to Me the fat and the blood,” says the Lord God. “They shall enter My sanctuary, and they shall come near My table to minister to Me, and they shall keep My charge. And it shall be, whenever they enter the gates of the inner court, that they shall put on linen garments; no wool shall come upon them while they minister within the gates of the inner court or within the house. They shall have linen turbans on their heads and linen trousers on their bodies; they shall not clothe themselves with anything that causes sweat. When they go out to the outer court, to the outer court to the people, they shall take off their garments in which they have ministered, leave them in the holy chambers, and put on other garments; and in their holy garments they shall not sanctify the people.
“They shall neither shave their heads nor let their hair grow long, but they shall keep their hair well trimmed. No priest shall drink wine when he enters the inner court. They shall not take as wife a widow or a divorced woman, but take virgins of the descendants of the house of Israel, or widows of priests.
“And they shall teach My people the difference between the holy and the unholy, and cause them to discern between the unclean and the clean. In controversy, they shall stand as judges, and judge it according to My judgments. They shall keep My laws and My statutes in all My appointed meetings, and they shall hallow My Sabbaths.
“They shall not defile themselves by coming near a dead person. Only for father or mother, for son or daughter, for brother or unmarried sister may they defile themselves. After he is cleansed, they shall count seven days for him. And on the day that he goes to the sanctuary to minister in the sanctuary, he must offer his sin offering in the inner court,” says the Lord God.
“It shall be, in regard to their inheritance, that I am their inheritance. You shall give them no possession in Israel, for I am their possession. They shall eat the grain offering, the sin offering, and the trespass offering; every dedicated thing in Israel shall be theirs. The best of all firstfruits of any kind, and every sacrifice of any kind from all your sacrifices shall be the priest’s; also you shall give to the priest the first of your ground meal, to cause a blessing to rest on your house. The priests shall not eat anything, bird or beast, that died naturally or was torn by wild beasts.

---

Several other statements you made in your answer make claims that are seemingly potentially true but not necessarily true, at least in accordance with the (lack of) evidence provided for such claims.

Perhaps the saints will rule with Christ, but we will rule the world, not mortals within the kingdom, as Zechariah 14:16 could also suggest?

Yes, we will rule the world or nations. The mortals will not be part of the kingdom, they will learn the ways of the Lord from the priests.

We will be able to minister to God:

Ezekiel 44:17-18 And it shall be, whenever they enter the gates of the inner court, that they shall put on linen garments; no wool shall come upon them while they minister within the gates of the inner court or within the house. They shall have linen turbans on their heads and linen trousers on their bodies; they shall not clothe themselves with anything that causes sweat.

We will also be able to minister to people where we will spend most of the time teaching:

Ezekiel 44:19 When they go out to the outer court, to the outer court to the people, they shall take off their garments in which they have ministered, leave them in the holy chambers, and put on other garments; and in their holy garments they shall not sanctify the people.

Psalm 2:8 - Berean Study Bible

Ask Me, and I will make the nations Your inheritance, the ends of the earth Your possession.

Revelation 2:26

And to the one who is victorious and continues in My work until the end, I will give authority over the nations.

Psalm 22:27 - Berean Study Bible

All the ends of the earth will remember and turn to the LORD. All the families of the nations will bow down before Him.

The verse below will continue until the final creation Jubilee

Psalm 51:13

Then I will teach transgressors Your ways, and sinners will return to You.

The fact that Satan, when he is loosed at the end of the Millennium, is able to corral an army of disgruntled rebels is evidence enough that unregenerate mankind will be a part of the Millennial Kingdom.

https://www.truthortradition.com/articles/the-millennial-kingdom-will-be-populated-by-three-categories-or-types-of-people

Where do you get this concept of "maturing from mortality to immortality", during the Millennium?

The Barley Harvest (the first-fruits or remnant)
The Wheat Harvest (the rest of the church)
The Grape Harvest (the nations or the world coming into the knowledge of Christ up to the final creation Jubilee)

Matthew 13, Luke 8, Mark 4 
Different level of revelatory understanding
- 30-fold (Outer Court)
- 60-fold (Holy Place)
-100-fold (Holy of Holies)

There will be people who will survive the tribulation. We have now reached the 6,000-period transition or 120th Jubilee from Pentecost into Tabernacles, this means that the evangelisation of the nations will continue during the Millennium until death is destroyed.

Micah 4:3 (NKJV)
He shall judge between many peoples, And rebuke strong nations afar off; They shall beat their swords into plowshares,  and their spears into [a]pruning hooks; Nation shall not lift up sword against nation, Neither shall they learn war anymore.

On this account, too, did the Lord assert that the kingdom of heaven was the portion of “the violent;” and He says, “The violent take it by force;” (Mat 11:12) that is, those who by strength and earnest striving axe on the watch to snatch it away on the moment. On this account also Paul the Apostle says to the Corinthians, “Know ye not, that they who run in a racecourse, do all indeed run, but one receiveth the prize? So run, that ye may obtain. Every one also who engages in the contest is temperate in all things: now these men [do it] that they may obtain a corruptible crown, but we an incorruptible. But I so run, not as uncertainty; I fight, not as One beating the air; but I make my body livid, and bring it into subjection, lest by any means, when preaching to others, I may myself be rendered a castaway.” (1Co 9:24-27) This able wrestler, therefore, exhorts us to the struggle for immortality, that we may be crowned, and may deem the crown precious, namely, that which is acquired by our struggle, but which does not encircle us of its own accord (sed non ultro coalitam).

Still further did He also make it manifest, that we ought, after our calling, to be also adorned with works of righteousness, so that the Spirit of God may rest upon us; for this is the wedding garment, of which also the apostle speaks, “Not for that we would be unclothed, but clothed upon, that mortality might be swallowed up by immortality.” (2Co 5:4) -

And thus in all things God has the pre-eminence, who alone is uncreated, the first of all things, and the primary cause of the existence of all, while all other things remain under God’s subjection. But being in subjection to God is continuance in immortality, and immortality is the glory of the uncreated One.

For it was necessary, at first, that nature should be exhibited; then, after that, that what was mortal should be conquered and swallowed up by immortality, and the corruptible by incorruptibility, and that man should be made after the image and likeness of God, having received the knowledge of good and evil.

(Ante-Nicene Fathers - Iranaeus - Against Heresies - Book 4 Ch 35-38)

————————————

*Lastly, In Revelation 21, the heavenly Jerusalem doesn't come down until after the new Heaven and Earth, which are clearly post-Millennium (Revelation 20).*

I do not dispute this fact.

iv. Who will be on the earth in the Millennium? Even after the rapture and the vast judgments of the Great Tribulation, there will be many people left on earth. After Jesus returns in glory, He will judge those who survive the Great Tribulation in the judgment of the nations (Mat 25:31-46). This is not a judgment unto salvation, but a judgment of moral worthiness, and entrance into the Millennial Kingdom of Jesus. The unworthy will be sent into eternal damnation, and the worthy will be allowed in Jesus’ Millennial Kingdom.

ii. During the Millennium, the citizens of earth will acknowledge and submit to the Lordship of Jesus. It will be a time of perfectly administrated enforced righteousness on this earth. (Isa 2:1-5)

b. Gather them together to battle: Who will these rebels be? They will be those who survive the Great Tribulation, enter into the Millennial Kingdom, and their descendants. “Infants born during the millennium will live to its conclusion and will not be required to make a choice between the devil and Christ until the end.” (Walvoord)

ix. During the Millennium, saints in their resurrected state will be given responsibility in the Millennial Earth according to their faithful service (Luk 19:11-27, Rev 20:4-6, Rev 2:26-28; Rev 3:12; Rev 3:22, 1Co 6:2-3).

ii. There are degrees of punishment for unbelievers, according to their works (Mat 11:20-24). Here is where they are sentenced to their specific eternal punishment.

(David Guzik)

So, believing Gentiles, Israel, and resurrected/raptured believers (all of whom have glorified bodies) will occupy the Earth. It should be noted, however, that believers with glorified bodies will not be reproducing. There is no marriage after this life (Matthew 22:30).

Children born during the millennial kingdom will have the responsibility of faith in Christ as all people of past ages have (faith in Christ since His coming; faith in God before—Genesis 15:2-6; Habakkuk 2:4; Romans 3:20). Unfortunately, not all of the children that are born during the millennial kingdom will come to faith in Christ. Those that do not will be led away by Satan into rebellion against God at the end of the millennial kingdom when Satan is let loose for a short time (Revelation 20:7-10).

https://www.gotquestions.org/millennial-kingdom.html

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE!  When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about us.

Comment: We saints will be the rulers of the kingdom - or, at least various different kinds of saints (Revelation 20:4). What you referenced from Ezekiel 44, however, speaks only of Levitical priests (Ezekiel 44:15).

Comment: Several other statements you made in your answer make claims that are seemingly potentially true but not necessarily true, at least in accordance with the (lack of) evidence provided for such claims. Perhaps the saints will rule with Christ, but we will rule the world, not mortals within the kingdom, as Zechariah 14:16 could also suggest? Where do you get this concept of "maturing from mortality to immortality", during the Millennium? Lastly, In Revelation 21, the heavenly Jerusalem doesn't come down until after the new Heaven and Earth, which are clearly post-Millennium (Revelation 20).

Comment: Why do you quote passages about the Levites? I was not contending against them being Levites, that was the whole point! The saints will be rulers of the kingdom; but, most saints are not Levites, nor priests.

Comment: Psalm 2:8 is referring specifically to Christ. See verse 7. "The fact that Satan, when he is loosed at the end of the Millennium, is able to corral an army of disgruntled rebels is evidence enough that unregenerate mankind will be a part of the Millennial Kingdom." Agreed, though the Millennial Kingdom is not necessarily the entire Earth. We know that somehow, in whatever way it happens, there will be unregenerate persons on Earth during the Millennium, but the Kingdom itself need not be over the entire Earth, and I think it's easier to say that it will not.

Comment: I concur with "Agreed, though the Millennial Kingdom is not necessarily the entire Earth. We know that somehow, in whatever way it happens, there will be unregenerate persons on Earth during the Millennium, but the Kingdom itself need not be over the entire Earth.

Comment: Overall, I like your first link, but what you say after that: the 3 harvests, 30-60-100, and the "120th Jubilee", I think are way over-applied passages that were not meant to be interpreted in the manner you are doing so. It just isn't called for or implied. Overall, I do think your answer to my original question is very suitable.